# How Does One Produce a Selenium Test with Database Fixture

Tags: selenium, phpunit, zend-test

Zend Test appears to rely upon Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase and Selenium appears to need PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase yet as far as I can tell PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to extend the `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`, you can initialize Selenium in your `setUp` method and close it in `tearDown`:

```
class GoogleTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase {

    private $selenium;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->selenium = new Testing_Selenium("*iexplore", "http://<your_url_under_the_test>");
        $this->selenium->start();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->selenium->stop();
    }

    // Your tests...

}
```